# Generate fixed value in json-schema faker

Tags: json, jsonschema, faker

I am trying to generate a type property on an object, with a default value, I read the documentation and found nothing related to giving a fixed value to a property.

You can view a link in the tester here: [Json-Schema-faker](http://json-schema-faker.js.org/#gist/269c64b0dd1d24dc190370b5cfb2f8a8/0.5.0-rc7)

This is the code I'm putting in the test faker:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "testModule"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "faker": "name.findName"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "faker": "internet.email"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "type",
    "name",
    "email"
  ]
}
```

The result I have:

```
{
  "type": "elit et aliqua",
  "name": "velit al",
  "email": "dolor ea in"
}
```

The result I would want:

```
{
  "type": "TestModule",
  "name": "velit al",
  "email": "dolor ea in"
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baptist

The only way I found to generate such results is using an enum with a single value.

In your case:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "testModule"
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "faker": "name.findName"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "faker": "internet.email"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "type",
    "name",
    "email"
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason stackoverflow is removing your name from the beginning of the message...

Comment: Certainly because my name is too long ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, we ended up creating our own factory, using fakerjs for the generation of fake datas.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 0.4.7 of JSON-schema-faker, there is the option `useDefaultValue` (but disabled by default) which does exactly this: if a `default` field with non empty value is provided, JSF will use that value in the generated JSON, instead of generating a random value.

https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/blob/v0.4.7/lib/index.js#L930-L932

Properly documented since version 0.5.0-rc.17: https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/tree/v0.5.0-rc17/docs#available-options

> `useDefaultValue` — If enabled, it will return the `default` value if present (default: `false`)

For completeness, there is also the `useExamplesValue` option, which similarly picks a random value among the provided `examples`, if any:

> `useExamplesValue` — If enabled, it will return a random value from `examples` if they're present (default: `false`)

In JSF demo website, you can activate these options by using the "options" button on the top left.